# Why it doesn't accept more than 2 charcters?

Tags: c++

I have the following function which counts the number of characters in a sentence

```
// A function to get a length of any sentence.
int length(char *str){
    int size = 0;
    while(str[size] != '\0'){
    size++;
    }
  return size;
}


int main(){
    char *name = new char;
    int cnt = 0;
    cin.getline(name, length(name));

    cout << length(name) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But when input a sentence and get its length, I found the sentence's length is just 2 characters.

**Why does that happen?**

Comment: This looks like C to me

Comment: @aaronman C doesn't have `new`, `cin`, or `endl`. By the way, `char* name = new char` is missing your dimensions.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour anyway because your one char is uninitialized. Why would you roll your own length function anyway? There's `strlen`, and, even better, `std::string`.

Comment: The Problem with your code is new char. The Problem with your question is that you should give the expected and the seen result/behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this:

```
char *name = new char;
```

You're only allocating 1 `char`, and that is not enough if you want to store into it something larger than 1 character (not to mention that you need another one for the null-terminator).

Instead try something like this:

```
char* name = new char[64];  // Be careful. Storing more than 64 characters will lead you to more or less the same error
cin.getline(name, 64);
...
delete[] name;  // Be sure to delete[] name
```

Better:

```
char name[64]; // Again, be careful to not store more than 64 characters
cin.getline(name, 64);
...
```

Best:

```
std::string name;  // The sane way to use strings
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

---

**UPDATE:**
If you want to get the length of the string using `std::string`, you can use `std::string::size()`

```
std::cout << name.size() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
char *name = new char;
```

allocates space for ***ONE*** char.

You rather want something like

```
char buf[0x100];
cin.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
```

instead. (You don't really need the dynamic memory allocation, and the logic is flawed - you don't know the length of the input beforehand, so `length(name)` doesn't make sense as the argument of `cin::getline()`.)

Ah, and the usual warning: why not `std::string`?

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

Comment: @LionKing That's why you should use the last approach involving `std::string` and `std::getline()`.

Answer (score 0):

you are "in the realm of undefined behaviour" starting from line 3 of your main, when you call `length` and start reading on "random" memory locations. This is probably what you meant

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char name[100];
    cin.getline(name, sizeof name );

    cout << sizeof name << ": " << name << endl;

  return 0;
}
```